# When to use max-width: none for block?

Tags: css

I explore third-party CSS code it consist this:

```
{
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 320px;
    padding: 40px 20px 40px 40px;
    max-width: none;
    max-height: none;
}
```

Why do we use `max-width: none` for block?

Comment: We don't.....it's irrelevant. If we did want something like that it would be `max-width:0` not none.

Comment: to make sure to override any potential max-width set somewhere

Comment: Could've been done to override styles elsewhere e.g. in media queries etc.

Comment: Maybe equivalent to `unset` . For  overriding some other rule purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default values for `max-width` and `max-height` is **none**. None meaning **No maximum width. This is default**. None value could be interpreted as **unset** in this case

Comment: It is not redundant. You can override other values eg. 150px with none